# What does Pantaflix stand for?

Tags: german-to-english, single-word-request

I saw a GIF that says

> Pantaflix Krass Freitag

I've found out that `Krass` means "awesome" and `Freitag` means "Friday".

What does Pantaflix mean?
I guess it means "Have" or "Enjoy", but I don't know.

Comment: A simple google search would have told you that *Pantaflix* is the name of a company (and not a German word).

Answer (score 1):

You've found a piece of marketing from [Pantaflix](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantaflix). Apparently, they want fridays to be associated with watching movies on their platform. [Here](https://giphy.com/pantaflix_demand) you can find more of their GIFs.

Pantaflix is a brand name and not a German word.